# Multiple USB Modems - Binding cdc-wdmx to symlink

Tags: usb, symlink, udev, networkmanager, gsm

First question here, long story short I have 3 different USB Cellular(GSM) modems and I want to ensure the connection profiles for each SIM (as the APNs differ) always go to the same modem/sim combo. The issue here is that due to the nature of USB the interfaces cdc-wdmx change on reboot and as the nmcli connection are tied to the interface name the connections dont come up.

So I have created symlinks using udev rules to point to the physical USB ports, the idea being modem 1 will always be the device plugged into the first USB port. This works and the symlinks point correctly however, I cant use the symlinks for the connection profiles for some reason.

To clarify a bit take the following example:

Modem & SIM combo A is vodafone. on boot up modem SIM combo A is assigned cdc-wdm0, this is the name that shows in NMCLI. I create a connection profile for vodafone with the apn 'internet' pointing at cdc-wdm0.The connection works.

Modem and SIM combo B is O2. On boot up medem SIM combo B is assigned cdc-wdm1, this is the name that also shows in NMCLI. I create a connection profile for O2 with the APN 'mobile.o2.co.uk' pointing at cdc-wdm1.The connection works.

But after a system reboot:

- Moden and SIM combo A is now assigned cdc-wdm1
- Modem and SIM combo B is now assigned cdc-wdm0

As a result my connections now don't work as the wrong APN's are configured.

My udev rules for the modems are as below, and these do work:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usbmisc", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="cdc-wdm*", KERNELS=="1-1:1.4", SYMLINK+="3rd-mdm"
SUBSYSTEM=="usbmisc", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="cdc-wdm*", KERNELS=="1-4.4", SYMLINK+="4th-mdm"
SUBSYSTEM=="usbmisc", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="cdc-wdm*", KERNELS=="1-2:1.4", SYMLINK+="1st-mdm"
SUBSYSTEM=="usbmisc", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="cdc-wdm*", KERNELS=="1-4.3", SYMLINK+="2nd-mdm"
```

and bthe symlink shows under a udevadm info:

```
[root@localhost rules.d]# udevadm info /dev/cdc-wdm1
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.3/1-4.3:1.4/usbmisc/cdc-wdm1
N: cdc-wdm1
**S: 2nd-mdm**
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/2nd-mdm
E: DEVNAME=/dev/cdc-wdm1
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.3/1-4.3:1.4/usbmisc/cdc-wdm1
E: ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
E: MAJOR=180
E: MINOR=177
E: SUBSYSTEM=usbmisc
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=88077
```

Can anyone please advise how I can get round this please?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question correctly, but it looks like your udev rules work, and now you only need to configure network manager to use the symlinks instead of the kernel assigned files, is that right? So have you actually tried to create connection profiles pointing to the symlinks?

Comment: Hi, I have tried creating a connection profile using the symlink, it rejects the symlink and says the connection profile requires an ifname. Do I need to use any syntax such as ' when using a symlink in network manager?

Comment: Ah, then you need udev rules to assign the right ifname, and not a symlink to the device node. My distro has those under `70-persistent-net`, you might look into these as a blueprint for your rules.

Comment: Wonderful, I will give it a look

Comment: Did you solve it?